# Customize media key behavior

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, media-player

You know these keyboards that have special keys to control media players? Like Play/Pause, Forward, Backwards etc.
I'm not entirely happy about their behavior and would like to change it.

As it is when I press the play/pause button, it usually plays or pauses my media player as it should. But when I have a media file selected in my file explorer, for example an mp3-file, then instead it opens that file with my media player. Even if my media player is already open and playing something else. I absolutely never want this to happen. I already have a key on my keyboard to open files, it's called 'Enter'.
So, is there a way to change this?